# Using Asp.net web forms to create a calculator same as windows

Tags: c#, asp.net, logic, calculator, code-behind

I'm asked to make a calculator with similar Windows calculator. I'm wondering where is the problem. I can press Button1 + Button2, But I can't Press the Button "=".
code behind there I Created a method for the "Equal_Click". But it seems not working. Is this because of the String couldn't be together with Bool? I kept pressing the "=" and it showed nothing. Did anyone see where the problem is?

**HERE IS MY FRONT CODE **

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="height: 369px; width: 363px">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="result" runat="server" Text="0" Height="34px" Width="216px" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox><br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="1" Height="36px" Width="41px" OnClick="Button_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="2" Height="36px" Width="41px" OnClick="Button_Click"/>
            <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="3" Height="36px" Width="41px" OnClick="Button_Click"/>  
            <asp:Button ID="Button14" runat="server" Text="+" Height="36px" Width="41px" OnClick="Operator_Click"/>
            <asp:Button ID="Button17" runat="server" Text="CE" Height="36px" Width="41px" OnClick="Button17_Click"/>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="4" Height="36px" Width="41px" OnClick="Button_Click"/>
            <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="5" Height="36px" Width="41px" OnClick="Button_Click"/>
            <asp:Button ID="Button6" runat="server" Text="6" Height="36px" Width="41px" OnClick="Button_Click"/>
            <asp:Button ID="Button13" runat="server" Text="-" Height="36px" Width="41px" OnClick="Operator_Click"/>
            <asp:Button ID="Button16" runat="server" Text="C" Height="36px" Width="41px"/>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button7" runat="server" Text="7" Height="36px" Width="41px" OnClick="Button_Click"/>
            <asp:Button ID="Button8" runat="server" Text="8" Height="36px" Width="41px" OnClick="Button_Click"/>
            <asp:Button ID="Button9" runat="server" Text="9" Height="36px" Width="41px" OnClick="Button_Click"/>
            <asp:Button ID="Button12" runat="server" Text="*" Height="36px" Width="41px" OnClick="Operator_Click"/>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button10" runat="server" Text="0" Height="36px" Width="86px" OnClick="Button_Click"/>
            <asp:Button ID="Button11" runat="server" Text="." Height="36px" Width="41px" OnClick="Operator_Click"/>
            <asp:Button ID="Button15" runat="server" Text="/" Height="36px" Width="41px" OnClick="Operator_Click"/>
            <asp:Button ID="Equal" runat="server" Text="=" Height="36px" Width="41px" OnClick="Equal_Click"/>
        </div>



    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**AND HERE IS MY CODE-BEHIND**
is there any wrong logic here?

```
public partial class calculator : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        Double value = 0;
        string operation = "";
        bool operation_press = false;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Equal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            operation_press = false;
            switch (operation)
            {
                case "+":
                    result.Text = (value + Double.Parse(result.Text)).ToString();
                    break;
                case "-":
                    result.Text = (value + Double.Parse(result.Text)).ToString();
                    break;
                case "*":
                    result.Text = (value + Double.Parse(result.Text)).ToString();
                    break;
                case "/":
                    result.Text = (value + Double.Parse(result.Text)).ToString();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }

        protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if ((result.Text == "0") || (operation_press))
                result.Text = string.Empty;

            Button b = (Button)sender;
            result.Text = result.Text + b.Text;
        }

        protected void Button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            result.Text = "0";
        }

        protected void Operator_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button b = (Button)sender;
            result.Text = result.Text + b.Text;
            //value = Convert.ToDouble(Double.Parse(result.Text);
            operation = b.Text;
            operation_press = true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: if i  use value = Double.Parse(result.Text); to store. It will have run-time error says that "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question before? And wasn't that closed?

Comment: Yes. I Deleted that post as I didn't write it properly. I clarify it and hope you guys understand what problem is this. @VDWWD

Comment: and my value is 0. @VDWWD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to convert the entire value of the TextBox to an interger. That cannot work because the TextBox also holds the `+` or `*` etc.
Furthermore the value of `operation` will always be empty when calculating the total because you do not save it in a state in `Operator_Click`.

```
protected void Equal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get the values for calculation
    int[] results = Regex.Split(result.Text, @"-|\+|\*|\/").Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();

    //get the operation
    string operation = Regex.Split(result.Text, @"[0-9]+")[1];

    //do the calculation
    switch (operation)
    {
        case "+":
            result.Text = (results[0] + results[1]).ToString();
            break;
        case "-":
            result.Text = (results[0] - results[1]).ToString();
            break;
        case "*":
            result.Text = (results[0] * results[1]).ToString();
            break;
        case "/":
            result.Text = (results[0] / results[1]).ToString();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: It still skipping all the switch of operation as it didn't have any value. When i press 1+1 and "=". It will show "1 + 1" instead

Comment: It Works. Thanks